# Elastic scripted aggregation of nested key/value pairs

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I want to have a scripted aggregation of key/value pairs in a nested array in elastic. An example of the documents returned is as follows:

```
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "testdan",
        "_type": "year",
        "_id": "AVtXirjYuoFS95t7pfkg",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "m_iYear": 2006,
          "m_iTopicID": 11,
          "m_People": [
            {
              "name": "Petrovic, Rade",
              "value": 3.70370364
            },
            {
              "name": "D. Kirovski",
              "value": 3.70370364
            }
]
}},
      {
        "_index": "testdan",
        "_type": "year",
        "_id": "AVtXirjYuoFS95t7pfkg",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "m_iYear": 2007,
          "m_iTopicID": 11,
          "m_People": [
            {
              "name": "Petrovic, Rade",
              "value": 6.70370364
            },
            {
              "name": "D. Kirovski",
              "value": 2.70370364
            }
]
}}
]
```

I would like to aggregate an average value for each person in m_Person over each document, as follows:

Petrovic, Rade = 3.70370364 + 6.70370364 / 2 = 7.05
D. Kirovski = 3.70370364 + 2.70370364 / 2 = 5.05

The division for the average should be calculated by the number of years that name appears.. One year may not show only one name for instance.

If this is more difficult due to not having unique IDs for people, I plan to add an ID for each person, but how would you go about scripting this so instead of returning all people, and needing to loop through at front-end, I can just have an array of people and their averages?

Comment: After undertaking more research, I am getting the impression that nested fields cannot be used with scripts. So for now I'm resorting to a front-end calculation. Will keep post updated.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to achieve this sort of aggregation by utilizing [Kibana Scripted Fields](https://www.elastic.co/blog/using-painless-kibana-scripted-fields). See the examples section. This assumes you are using Elasticsearch 5.0 as the scripting language is Painless.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieved this with a nested aggregation pretty easily. For each year, we're aggregating on the people's names and then computing the average value for each of them.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "years": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "m_iYear"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "names": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "m_People"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "names": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "m_People.name"
              },
              "aggs": {
                "average": {
                  "avg": {
                    "field": "m_People.value"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I get the following:

`"type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [m_People.name] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory."` Can you send fielddata = true with nested field?

Comment: Ok, you need to create a `keyword` sub-field for the `m_People.name` field so that you can aggregate on it.

Comment: Ok I'm looking into how to do this when creating the mapping. At moment we have in c#: `client.CreateIndex(szIndexName, a => a
                    .Mappings(ms => ms
                        .Map<TopicYear>(m => m.AutoMap()
                        .Properties(ps => ps
                    .Nested<Entity>(n => n
                        .Name(c => c.m_People)
                    )
                ))
                    ));`
Entity object has name and value for a person. But want to say m_People.name is a keyword field.

Comment: Have a look over here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/fluent-mapping.html

Comment: Yes it worked. Although the returned people count is about 8 with the aggregation, when I know that there are 100 people for one of the years. So I'm not sure if it only shows people that appear in each year, and so reduces it to 8.. Looking into this soon.

Comment: Ok, let me know if you need more help with this.